# JSP invalid file path

Tags: java, file, jsp

I'm getting the error File Not Found in my JSP page, here is the image of the filepath and the path i'm using... Can someone tell my what i'm doing wrong?

```
String xmlFileName = "WebContent\\xml_servidor\\parques.xml"
```

[File Path](http://i.gyazo.com/42a00d377dda4c09e376d3e5a6c978c1.png)

I used the same path in my java application and it worked out fine...

Comment: What are you doing with this string? Can you show the code where you use `xmlFileName`? It's just a string on it's own so it doesn't really show us any context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's searching in the file where you have the eclipse files? Have you checked the error path?

Answer (score 0):

You would try with

```
String xmlFileName = "xml_servidor\\parques.xml"
```

parque.jsp is inside WebContent